# Detect double click on images in javascript

Tags: javascript

Any suggestion what is the most convenient way to detect if a double click event was not on text, but on images (or other elements on the websites)?

More info: at the moment, I use "`document.addEventListener("dblclick", getSelectedText);`" to get a double-clicked word on the website. But many users of my extension complain that they often mistakenly double click on images etc... so I want to eliminate those double-clicked events.

Comment: You can simply add event listener on image element (not on entire document).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `getSelectedText` you could call a wrapping function that checks the target element's tag type:

```
function ignoreTargetImages (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    // element is an image, so handle differently or ignore
  } else {
    getSelectedText(event);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("dblclick", ignoreTargetImages);
```

Comment: An additional question to this solution - I want that "getSelectedText(event)" work ONLY for text. In the upper solution, the user can still double-click on button or other elements which are not text. What are the most usual elements like "IMG" except text? I want that function won't react if user double-click on unsupported elements.

Comment: There's no specific way to detect text itself. It will depend entirely on how you decide to structure your DOM. The best solution would probably to flag each element that is _not_ supposed to be clicked with a class that you can check for.

Comment: A little more explanation of what I want to achieve. I developing a dictionary browser extension that reacts on double click on a word. Some of the test users comment that they don't want extension reacts if they double click on an image, button ... just when double-click is on pure text on the website. Your code above works as expected but only for events on images. In your IF statement, I add also checking for Button, but there can be many different (unwanted) elements on the website.

Comment: If you don't have control over the DOM element it will be very difficult to reliably detect text. Websites can have text inside a huge variety of tags in a variety of different structures.
You might try using `Element.innerHTML` to see if there's some way you can determine if the inner HTML has plain text or not, but it would involve parsing the resulting string

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function which only calls your `getSelectedText` method if the double click was not on one or more ignored tags

```js
function ignoreTags(ignoreTags, fn){
  return function(e){
    if(!ignoreTags.includes(e.target.tagName)) 
      fn(e);
  }
}

function getSelectedText(e) { console.log("get the text") }

document.addEventListener("dblclick", ignoreTags(["IMG"],getSelectedText));
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
```

This would allow you to add to the list of ignored tags should you need to.

Comment: What is ``fn(e)`` mean here?

Comment: Oh I see that it is a ``function``. Just another example why we should always stick with clear naming conventions rather than shortcuts.

Comment: @em_code `function` is a reserved word in js. I can't see how it could be any clearer that `fn` is a referencwe to a function. Maybe `func`

Comment: You are right @Jamiec, but I would still go with something like ``helperFunction`` or even maybe ``getSelectedText`` in this example which makes it way easier to understand.

Comment: There's no pint calling it `getSelectedText` as you could pass _any_ function to that argument. The method `ignoreTags` is supposed to be a general purpose helper which lets you ignore events on a specified set of tags. This literally could not be any clearer to anyone used to javascript code.

Comment: Dunno why you took that too personal but I am not gonna argue here how unclear that code is. Enjoy your day @Jamiec.